# Add a foregin key to a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add `username` from my `st_accounts` column into my table `results` using mySQL.

**st_accounts table**

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,    //Primary Key
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**results table**

```
  `score_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,     //Primary key
  `score` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
create table accounts (
  account_id int auto_increment primary key,
   . . .
);

create table results (
  result_id int auto_increment primary key,
  account_id int not null
  score int NOT NULL,
  score_date date NOT NULL,
  constraint fk_results_accounts foreig key (accounts_id) references accounts(account_id)
) ;
```

Notes:

- Declare the `primary key` explicitly, not in a comment.
- My convention is to name the primary key after the name of the table (in singular) with `_id` after it.
- The foreign key has the same name as the primary key -- self documenting.
- I made the integer primary keys `auto_increment`, so the database can assign unique values.

Comment: I already have an accounts table used for registration and login though.